# Handling segmentation fault within a client function/request

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a simple local C server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 10
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

struct PARAM{
    int client_socket;
};

void *handle_client(void *arg) {
    struct PARAM *args = arg;
    int client_socket = args->client_socket;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    // Read client message
    if (read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0) {
        perror("Error reading from client");
        close(client_socket);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    // Creating an error
    char *str;
    printf("%s\n", str+1);
    
    char formattedHeader[256]={0};
    sprintf(formattedHeader,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %lu\r\n\r\nTEST",(long)4);

    if (write(client_socket, formattedHeader, strlen(formattedHeader)) < 0) {perror("Error writing to client");}
    free(args);
    close(client_socket);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    pthread_t tid;

    if ((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {perror("Error creating server socket"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(12345);

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {perror("Error binding server socket"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    if (listen(server_socket, MAX_CLIENTS) == -1) {perror("Error listening for connections"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    printf("Server listening on port 12345\n");

    while (1) {
        socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);
        if ((client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_length)) == -1) {perror("Error accepting client connection"); continue;}
        struct PARAM *item = malloc(sizeof(struct PARAM));
        item->client_socket=client_socket;
        if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, handle_client, item) != 0) {perror("Error creating thread"); close(client_socket); continue;}
        pthread_detach(tid);
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

I had debugged the code, but in an unlikely event of an error in a single client request, the entire server will crash.

Is it possible to report the error to the client instead of crashing the server?

I made some attempts to move the instruction pointer by sigaction, but no luck.

Comment: You made some attempts with the sigaction, had some issues with it and don't want to show it? Removing the tag [tag:sigaction] as not used in the Q.

Comment: @273K I assumed showing the basic attempt was superfluous. Evidently, I caught the SIGSEGV signal by sigaction but stuck within the sigaction handler without actually moving the instruction pointer to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reasonable way for processes to continue running after receiving an unexpected segfault. If you don't want a segfault from serving one particular request to crash your whole server, then you need to design it so that it forks off child processes to handle requests, letting them die and replacing them when they segfault.